# How to handle option click on a status item?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I know you can assign a custom view that overrides `mouseDown:` method. I'm looking for a standard solution since I don't want to re-implement drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this wherever you need it in your code:

```
if ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)
{
  //whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: I use a menu rather than target/action. Is it guaranteed that modifier flags isn't changed when `menuNeedsUpdate:` is called?

Comment: It shouldn't change. According to the docs, modifierFlags is independent of any other events floating around the app. I think you should give it a shot.